# I am using select top 5 from(select * from tbl2) tbl, will it get all records from tbl2 or will it get only specific records i.e 5

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using select top 5 from(select * from tbl2) tbl, will it get all records from tbl2 and then it will it get only specific records i.e 5? or do it only get 5 records from internal memory. suppose we have 1000 records in tbl2.

Comment: Run the query and see what happens

Comment: hi I have run and definitly get 5 records.but I want to know it conceptually how it works ? can you please read my question.

Comment: Look at the execution plan :) BTW, your "top 5" can be different each time your query is ran since you didn't specify an order by. If you get the same results each time, understand this isn't guaranteed. Never use TOP without ORDER BY unless you don't care what records you get back. Also, Your sub-query is uncorrelated so there is no Parent / Child relationship here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, SQL actually has a huge amount of amazing documentation/resources online. For instance: [This google search.](http://www.google.com/search?q=SELECT%20TOP%20SQL)

As to your question, it will pull the top five results matching your criteria, so it depends. It'll go through, and find the first five results matching your criteria. If those are the last results it goes through, it'll still have to do the comparisons and filtering on all rows, the only difference will be that it will have to send less rows to your computer.

For example, let's say we have a table `my_table` with two columns: Customer_ID (which is unique) and First_Purchase_Date (which is a `date` value between 2015-01-01 and 2017-07-26). If we simply do `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM my_table` then it will go through and pull the first five rows it finds, without looking at the rest of the rows. On the other hand, if we do `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM my_table WHERE First_Purchase_Date = '2017-05-17'` then it will have to go through all the rows until it can find five rows with a `First_Purchase_Date` of 2017-05-17. If `First_Purchase_Date` is indexed, this should not be very expensive, as it'll more or less know where to look. If it's not, then it depends on your how SQL has decided to structure your table, and if it has created any useful statistics. Worst case, it could not have any statistics and the desired rows could be the last five in the database, in which case it will have to complete the comparison on all the rows in the database.

By the way, this is a somewhat poor idea, as the columns returned will not necessarily stay consistent over time. It may be a good idea to throw in an `ORDER BY` clause, to ensure you get the same records every time.

Comment: Yes I a getting your point but can you understand that  
"I am asking that in a subquery will the subquery first get all results if we have only specified top in Parent select and not in child query?"

Comment: @AliNafeesDhillon Added an example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

The SELECT TOP clause is used to specify the number of records to return.

It limits the rows returned in a query result set to a specified number of rows or percentage of rows. When TOP is used in conjunction with the ORDER BY clause, the result set is limited to the first N number of ordered rows; otherwise, it returns the first N number of rows in an undefined order.

SELECT TOP number|percent column_name(s)
     FROM table_name
    WHERE condition;

Comment: I am asking that in a subquery will the subquery first get all results if we have only specified top in Parent select and not in child query?

Comment: Yes because your Parent query will get the TOP 5 records from the result in your subquery,